# Homebrew issues error while calling 'brew update'

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, homebrew

I don't have much knowledge of all this so please forgive my incompetence. When I run `brew update`, it shows:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/usr/local/Library/Taps/homebrew-science/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
Error: Failed to update tap: homebrew/science
Already up-to-date.
```

But, when I do `sudo brew update`, it says:

```
bash-3.2$ sudo brew update
Password:
Already up-to-date.
```

Why does it flag the fatal warning when I run the command without `sudo`? FYI, to provide some context I am trying to install **Octave** regarding which I need to run `brew tap homebrew/science`.

Please let me know how should I fix this. If possible, kindly provide a link to a page/article where I can understand the reason for the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `index.lock` file which is located in a directory which might need root permission to modify it or its files. You can change the permission of a directory using the `chmod` command.

This is what you can do:
`sudo chmod -R +w /path/to/directory`

A good choice for `directory` in this case might be `'/usr/local/Library/Taps/'`

The -R option will recursively execute the command on sub directories and files.

The +w option will add write permission to the mentioned directory or file for everyone.

Good Luck. ;)